# Preparing trimmed means of multiple data files for repeated mesaures anova

Tags: r

I have multiple data files (in tab separated txt files) formatted like so:

Made some example files

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B20HmmYd0lsFVGhTQ0EzRFFmYXc/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B20HmmYd0lsFbWxmQzV6X0o2Y1E/edit?usp=sharing

```
Condition  Block Session Stimuli    Score   Reqrespons Act RT extra
 X          3      3    asdfa        1           a      a  500  0
 Y          1      2    qewrq        0           b      a  1100 0
```

I want to exclude outlying RTs and perform ANOVA on the means of RT and score of the files(with factor condition). So far, I've done this in an extremely ugly fashion and have rows by subject (I'd prefer to format it with rows as subjectxcondition).

My current attempt uses a for loop :

```
all_data<-data.frame(rbind(1:27)) #make empty data.frame 
all_data
for(i in 1:2)
{
n= paste(i,".txt", sep="")
a<- sprintf("table%d", i, i)
data <- read.table(toString(n), header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

I fill out cols 1:9 with scores 1-9

```
Score<-as.vector(tapply(data$Score,list(data$Condition,data$Reqresponse),mean))

for(o in 1:9)
{
all_data [i, o] <- Score[o]
}
```

Then trim my RT values in the way i want to and put in cols 10 on of all_data

```
data <- data[which(data$RT>200),]
data <- do.call(rbind,by(data,data$Condition,function(x) x[!abs(scale(x$RT)) > 3,] ))
RT<-as.vector(tapply(data$RT,list(data$Condition,data$Reqresponse, data$Score),mean))
for(j in 1:18)
{
all_data [i, j+9] <- RT[j]
}
}
```

Also this code must be aesthetically offensive to anyone decent in R, please tell me how to fix that up if you like

Comment: Hi luke. It's a bit hard for anyone to help you at the moment as we don't have good examples of the contents of 1.txt, 2.txt. The example data you've posted doesn't have the necessary tabs to be read in by `read.table()`. Perhaps you could upload 1.txt and 2.txt to Google Docs or something similar and link to them?

Comment: Ok I'll make my example data better, sec!

Comment: on 2nd thoughts ill make an example data file and upload it.

Comment: @luke123 what is `all_data`? and here `for(o in 1:9)all_data [i, o] <- Score[o]` you loop over without defining `i`?!! does `i` the file index?

Comment: yeah is the file index. all_data is a frame wit hmeans for each data file occupying a row. IDeally i'd like means for each condition for each data file occupying a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using `ddply` from `plyr` package. For example:

```
require(plyr)
res <- lapply(list.files(pattern='^[1-2].txt'),function(ff){
  ## you read the file 
  data <-  read.table(ff, header=T, quote="\"")
  ## remove the outlier
  data <- data[data$RT>200,]
  data <-  ddply(data,.(Condition),function(x) x[!abs(scale(x$RT)) > 3,])
  ## compute the mean
  ddply(data,.(Condition,Reqresponse,Score),summarise,RT=mean(RT))
})

[[1]]
   Condition Reqresponse Score   RT
1          X           a     0  500
2          X           a     1  750
3          X           b     0  500
4          X           b     1  500
5          Y           a     0  400
6          Y           a     1  640
7          Y           b     1 1000
8          Z           a     0 1000
9          Z           a     1 1675
10         Z           b     0  400

[[2]]
   Condition Reqresponse Score   RT
1          X           a     0  500
2          X           a     1  750
3          X           b     0  500
4          X           b     1  500
5          Y           a     0  400
6          Y           a     1  640
7          Y           b     1 1000
8          Z           a     0 1000
9          Z           a     1 1675
10         Z           b     0  400
```

Comment: 1 thing I have in my for loop which allows me to reverse score certain data files, based on their file name, to make them all comparable is
i %in% c(2,4,6,7,9,11,14,16,18,19,21,23,25,28,30,32,34,36)
{ do the reverse scoring stuff}           , can you think of a way to embed this in the plyr function?

Comment: @luke123 yu have removed this line from your OP..do you talk about 
`seq(from = 1, to = 4001, by=500)...`? But does this result is near from what you expected?

Comment: yes, the result is great cheers -- it was a line that I thought was bloating my original post but now I think I should've included.   certain files have response a and b backwards, I wrote in script to reverse like so i %in% c(2,4,6,7,9,11,14,16,18,19,21,23,25,28,30,32,34,36)
{
data$Reqresponse[data$Reqresponse == "a"] <- "TMP"
data$Reqresponse[data$Reqresponse == "b"] <- "a"
data$Reqresponse[data$Reqresponse == "TMP"] <- "b"
}           Not sure if I can do this based on file name without the loop (the i determines which files). I can always reverse these values in excel but id rather not